# Powering options for Arduino project

Tags: power-supply, arduino, power, lcd, hc-05

For my project, I have these components:

1. Arduino Mega 2560 Rev 3
2. [HC-05](https://core-electronics.com.au/bluetooth-module-hc-05.html) Bluetooth module
3. [LCD display](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/images/10166911008798/XC4617-dataSheetMain.pdf)
4. [Logic Level Shifter](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/images/10129661165598/XC4486-dataSheetMain.pdf)

Currently I am powering the Arduino Mega using the Vin and GND pins via 6 AA batteries (~9 V). The Arduino Mega 5 V, 3.3 V, and GND pins are used to send the voltage out to the other components listed above.

I have noticed that when the 6 AA batteries somewhat drain out, the LCD drops in brightness and HC-05 almost fully goes off. Even if the LCD drops in brightness, I still want the HC-05 working.

Any suggestions on improving the power connections to get a longer lasting system? I was thinking using two power supplies (one for the Arduino and LCD and the other for just the HC-05). Is that a valid solution?

Comment: Does it need to be the Arduino Mega? It won't be very power efficient. For a battery project would be better a smaller devboard like the Arduino Mini or even an ESP32 that has already bluetooth integrated. And everything working at 3.3 V. There are many displays, most of them, that work at 3.3 V and are very cheap also.

Comment: Does it have to be powered by batteries? Using the onboard barrel jack may be a better idea(>9V only, I fried my UNO plugging a 24V power supply in).